# Make the Input box to read, not select and delete the data

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible that the you can only add data in the input box but not select and then delete the data.

How should I do it in jQuery UI?

Thanks!

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#from").datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,      
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",      
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


  
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```